# Django inner join with search terms for tables across many-to-many relationships

Tags: django, orm, inner-join

I have a dynamic hierarchical advanced  search interface I created. Basically, it allows you to search terms, from about 6 or 7 tables that are all linked together, that can be and'ed or or'ed together in any combination. The search entries in the form are all compiled into a complex Q expression.

I discovered a problem today. If I provide a search term for a field in a many-to-many related sub-table, the output table can include results from that table that don't match the term.

My problem can by reproduced in the shell with a simple query:

```
qs = PeakGroup.objects.filter(msrun__sample__animal__studies__id__exact=3)
sqs = qs[0].msrun.sample.animal.studies.all()
sqs.count()
#result: 2
```

Specifically:

```
In [3]: qs = PeakGroup.objects.filter(msrun__sample__animal__studies__id__exact=3)
In [12]: ss = s[0].msrun.sample.animal.studies.all()

In [13]: ss[0].__dict__
Out[13]: 
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x7fc12bfbf940>,
 'id': 3,
 'name': 'Small OBOB',
 'description': ''}

In [14]: ss[1].__dict__
Out[14]: 
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x7fc12bea81f0>,
 'id': 1,
 'name': 'obob_fasted',
 'description': ''}
```

The `id`s in `sqs` queryset include 1 & 3 even though I only searched on 3.  I don't get back literally **all** studies, so it is filtering some un-matching study records.  I understand why I see that, but I don't know how to execute a query that treats it like a join I could perform in SQL where I can restrict the results to only include records that match the query, instead of getting back only records in the root model and gathering everything left-joined to those root model records.

Is there a way to do such an inner join (as the result of a single complex Q expression in a filter) on the entire set of linked tables so that I only get back records that match the M:M field search term?

*UPDATE*:

By looking at the SQL:

```
In [3]: str(s.query)
Out[3]: 'SELECT "DataRepo_peakgroup"."id", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."name", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."formula", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."msrun_id", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."peak_group_set_id" FROM "DataRepo_peakgroup" INNER JOIN "DataRepo_msrun" ON ("DataRepo_peakgroup"."msrun_id" = "DataRepo_msrun"."id") INNER JOIN "DataRepo_sample" ON ("DataRepo_msrun"."sample_id" = "DataRepo_sample"."id") INNER JOIN "DataRepo_animal" ON ("DataRepo_sample"."animal_id" = "DataRepo_animal"."id") INNER JOIN "DataRepo_animal_studies" ON ("DataRepo_animal"."id" = "DataRepo_animal_studies"."animal_id") WHERE "DataRepo_animal_studies"."study_id" = 3 ORDER BY "DataRepo_peakgroup"."name" ASC'
```

...I can see that the query is as specific as I would like it to be, but in the template, how do I specify that I want what I would have seen in the SQL result, had I supplied all of the specific  related table fields I wanted to see in the output?  E.g.:

`SELECT "DataRepo_peakgroup"."id", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."name", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."formula", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."msrun_id", "DataRepo_peakgroup"."peak_group_set_id"`**`, "DataRepo_animal_studies"."study_id"`** `FROM "DataRepo_peakgroup" INNER JOIN "DataRepo_msrun" ON ("DataRepo_peakgroup"."msrun_id" = "DataRepo_msrun"."id") INNER JOIN "DataRepo_sample" ON ("DataRepo_msrun"."sample_id" = "DataRepo_sample"."id") INNER JOIN "DataRepo_animal" ON ("DataRepo_sample"."animal_id" = "DataRepo_animal"."id") INNER JOIN "DataRepo_animal_studies" ON ("DataRepo_animal"."id" = "DataRepo_animal_studies"."animal_id") WHERE "DataRepo_animal_studies"."study_id" = 3 ORDER BY "DataRepo_peakgroup"."name" ASC`

Comment: It's like - I need to eliminate the `.all()` step. Have everything in one big compiled Table before the complex `Q` expression is applied. Perhaps I need a custom SQL query? I haven't tried a custom query in Django yet. Can you get queryset objects from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Django ORM gives you back from a query (whose filters use fields from many-to-many [henceforth "M:M"] related tables), is a set of records from the "root" table from which the query started.  It uses the join logic that you would use in an SQL query, obtaining records using the foreign keys, so you are guaranteed to get back root table records that DO link to *a* M:M related table record that matches your search term, but when you send the root table records(/queryset) to be rendered in a template and insert a nested loop to access records from the M:M related table, it always gets *everything* linked to that root table record - whether they match your search term or not, so if you get back a root table record that links to multiple records in an M:M related table, at least 1 record is guaranteed to match your search term, but other records may not.

In order to get the *inner* join (i.e. only including combined records that match search terms in the table(s) queried), you simply have to roll-your-own, because Django doesn't support it.  I accomplished this in the following way:

When rendering search results, wherever you want to include records from a M:M related table, you have to create a nested loop.  At the inner-most loop, I essentially re-enforce that the record matches all of the search terms.  I.e. I implement my own filter using conditionals on each combination of records (from the root table and from each of the M:M related table).  If any record combination does not match, I skip it.

Regarding the particulars as to how I did that, I won't get too into the weeds, but at each nested loop, I maintain a dict of its key path (e.g. `msrun__sample__animal__studies`) as the key and the current record as the value.  I then use a custom `simple_tag` to re-run the search terms against the current record from each table (by checking the key path of the search term against those available in the dict).

Alternatively, you could do this in the view by compiling all of the matching records and sending the combined large table to the template - but I opted not to do this because of the hurdles surrounding cached_properties and since I already pass the search term form data to re-display the executed search form, the structure of the search was already available.

*Watch out #1* - Even without "refiltering" the combined records in the template, note that the record count *can* be inaccurate when dealing with a combined/composite/joined table.  To ensure that the number of records I report in my header above the table was always correct/accurate (i.e. represented the number of rows in my html table), I kept track of the filtered count and used javascript under the table to update the record count reported at the top.

*Watch out #2* - There is one other thing to keep in mind when querying using terms from M:M related tables.  For every M:M related table record that matches the search term, you will get back a duplicate record from the root table, and there's no way to tell the difference between them (i.e. which M:M record/field value matched in each case.  For example, if you matched 2 records from an M:M related table, you would get back 2 identical root table records, and when you pass that data to the template, you would end up with 4 rows in your results, each with the same data from the root table record.  To avoid this, all you have to do is append the `.distinct()` filter to you results queryset.